# virsh autostart not working

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, virsh

```
root@virtual3:~# virsh autostart nstest
Domain nstest marked as autostarted

root@virtual3:~# virsh dominfo nstest 
Id:             -
Name:           nstest
UUID:           8cf691cd-7246-442b-a26b-3580e24600c5
OS Type:        hvm
State:          shut off
CPU(s):         2
Max memory:     6291456 KiB
Used memory:    2097152 KiB
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      disable
Managed save:   no
Security model: apparmor
Security DOI:   0

root@virtual3:~#
```

What am I doing wrong? The domain xml is listed in /etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart but still no autostart :(

Nothing in the logs :((

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem (2/3/22) and found a solution now (2/7/22).

**Problem:** I was having the same problems too.  It's never happened before. On one Centos 7 host, the first 3 VMs I had previously set to autostart was working fine (I could enable and disable autostart). But I had 4 others that had previously autostarted, now were set to not do so, and that I could not enable.  I usually use the UI.  If I click for autostart, save, and come back, it's not checked even though it should be.  So I tried it per the command line it didn't work either and I discovered what you discovered above.  Rebooting either the clients or the host machine makes no difference. Whether a client VM is running or shut off makes no difference.

**Solution.**  It seems like something was getting out of sync.  What, I'm not sure. The problem isn't apparently something saved in the virtual machine .xml file.  While I never discovered exactly what was wrong, I did find figure out how to fix it.  Anything set to autostart should have an entry in /etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart/ named something like machinename.xml containing a symbolic link to the virtual machine's xml configure file of the same name in /etc/libvirt/qemu/. **Delete the symbolic link for the problematic clients in the /etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart directory** (make sure you don’t delete the source xml in the qemu directory). Now when you try to turn on autostart either via the UI or with via ‘virsh autostart machinename’.  I deleted the autostart/*xml files for the 4 problem clients, and then turned one on and off repeatedly via the UI, and the other 3 via the command line, and everything performs normal for me now...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I had a file in the autostart folder and not a link.

```
root@kvm1630:/etc/libvirt/qemu # ls -l 
-rw------- 1 root root  7982 févr. 18 15:17 hebergement.xml

root@kvm1630:/etc/libvirt/qemu # ls -l autostart/
-rwx------ 1 root root 6195 avril 16  2021 hebergement.xml*
```

Solution: delete the file and create a symbolic link.

```
root@kvm1630:/etc/libvirt/qemu # rm autostart/hebergement.xml
rm: remove regular file 'autostart/hebergement.xml'? y
```

Then run the command again to make the VM autostart:

```
root@kvm1630:/etc/libvirt/qemu # virsh autostart hebergement
Domain hebergement marked as autostarted

root@kvm1630:/etc/libvirt/qemu # ls -l autostart/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 févr. 18 15:49 hebergement.xml -> /etc/libvirt/qemu/hebergement.xml
```

We finally check that the VM is indeed autostart.

```
root@kvm1630:/etc/libvirt/qemu # virsh dominfo hebergement
Id:             9
Name:           hebergement
UUID:           74590197-8b3a-4bed-95e6-653ce7c456af
OS Type:        hvm
State:          running
CPU(s):         1
CPU time:       6614,7s
Max memory:     8388608 KiB
Used memory:    8388608 KiB
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      enable
Managed save:   no
Security model: none
Security DOI:   0
```

FYI, I use fi-backup [a LibVirtKvm-script](https://github.com/dguerri/LibVirtKvm-scripts/blob/master/fi-backup.sh) to create VM snapshots every hour... Consequence: the VM definition xml file is changed every hour like so:

```
root@kvm1630:/etc/libvirt/qemu # colordiff hebergement.xml autostart/hebergement.xml
46,83c48
<       <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-151710'/>
<       <backingStore type='file'>
<         <format type='qcow2'/>
<         <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-141710'/>
<         <backingStore type='file'>
<           <format type='qcow2'/>
<           <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-131710'/>
<           <backingStore type='file'>
<             <format type='qcow2'/>
<             <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-121709'/>
<             <backingStore type='file'>
<               <format type='qcow2'/>
<               <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-111709'/>
<               <backingStore type='file'>
<                 <format type='qcow2'/>
<                 <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-101711'/>
<                 <backingStore type='file'>
<                   <format type='qcow2'/>
<                   <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-091738'/>
<                   <backingStore type='file'>
<                     <format type='qcow2'/>
<                     <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-091200'/>
<                     <backingStore type='file'>
<                       <format type='qcow2'/>
<                       <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20220218-082151'/>
<                       <backingStore type='file'>
<                         <format type='qcow2'/>
<                         <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.qcow2'/>
<                         <backingStore/>
<                       </backingStore>
<                     </backingStore>
<                   </backingStore>
<                 </backingStore>
<               </backingStore>
<             </backingStore>
<           </backingStore>
<         </backingStore>
<       </backingStore>
---
>       <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/hebergement.bimg-20210415-011726'/>
```

hope it helps

Ernest.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting that setting 'autostart' will *immediately* start the VM.  However, that's not the intended effect of autostart.  Rather, it's solely there to ensure the VM starts automatically at *boot time* for the host.  From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/virsh):

> Configure a domain to be automatically started at boot.

If you then want to actually start the VM immediately, you need to do so with `virsh start`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear - it still doesn't autostart even when i reboot the server. Nothing at all in the logs. "nstest.xml" is listed in /etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart  :(